# Get the return value when running a command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command

I have a command to run : `vsinstr -coverage hello.exe`, and it returns error code with the following message to the stderr : Error VSP1018: VSInstr does not support processing binaries that are already instrumented..

How can I get the error code when I run this command in batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `%errorlevel%` within the batch code following the call to the .exe should reference the returned error code. (However, if you need to access that "VSP1018" value, well, I'm not sure how or if you even can reference the error *message*.)